# Change slice URL without refresh the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to remove value from URL(window.location) without page refresh and add value in URL without reloading the page.

I used `history.pushState()` but i can't get perfect output.

```
history.pushState(null, null, '28');
```

This is base URL

```
https://www.example.com/color/27-28/fruits/1-2
```

NEW URL (Remove value) :- https://www.example.com/color/27/fruits/1-2

NEW URL (Add value) :- https://www.example.com/color/27-28-29/fruits/1-2

How to do it?

Please help me.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: For clarity, are you saying you want to change the window.location and *not* reload the page?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Modify the URL without reloading the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page)